# Adding IPVS to the kernel

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I am trying to setup keepalived on a pair of VPS load balancer servers. I have hit the road block of IPVS not being included with the kernal.

```
IPVS: Can't initialize ipvs: Protocol not available
```

I am not familiar on the best way to add support for this, I believe it may be possible with a kernel module but I am unclear how to proceed.

Comment: I can not tell from your question if you need to build the kernel module or if the kernel module will not load or if there is a bug. Can  you please tell us , what distro ? What kernel version ?

Comment: have u found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, install ipvs, by running

```
yum install ipvsadm
```

Once done, run,

```
  modprobe ip_vs
```

on your host machine, or the machine keepalived is to be installed on. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To me only worked editing `/etc/modules` adding a new line with `ip_vs`.
After this the module started to be loaded at boot.

Comment: `/etc/modules` is often a symlink nowadays to `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`